# const boost::array<T,N> or boost::array<const T,N>?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

What is difference between these two? Which one you would prefer when you need a fixed size array of constant values?

```
const boost::array<int, 2> x = {0, 1};
boost::array<const int, 2> y = {0, 1};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one will prevent that you copy it to a new non-const array

```
boost::array<const int, 2> y = {0, 1};
boost::array<int, 2> y1 = y; // error!
```

Since I would expect that to work, I would probably go with the first option. Passing the second one to templates that expect a `boost::array<T, N>` will prevent those templates from modifying their parameter (even if it's a copy). The first one would "just work", since the parameter would have the type `boost::array<int, 2>`.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, why pass by value disregards const qualifier? Is it how argument type deduction works?

Comment: @pic yes. It think it's a good thing. See the comments on http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/04/appearing-and-disappearing-consts-in-c/

Comment: Schaub. Yes, it makes perfect sense. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

It's really a stylistic difference.

If you try to call `assign` on a `const array`, the compiler error says there is no matching function. If you do the same with an `array<const T>`, it points at the invalid operation inside `assign`.

I think `const array` expresses intent better, and looks more like the corresponding C-style array declaration. But I wouldn't make an effort to change things, for example in legacy code or inside a template which might generate an `array<const T>`.

Comment: I will go with **const array**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `const int` and an `int` in this context are pretty much the same. There's nothing you can do to an `array<int,2>` that you can't do to an `array<const int, 2>`. If instead of `int` you have some class then there would be a difference. with `array<const MyClass, 2>` you would not be able to call non-const methods on the elements of the array.
`const array<MyClass, 2>` is stronger in that you cannot modify anything what so ever. You can't call non-const methods of the elements **and** you can't change the array itself by replacing the elements, say using `operator[]`.

Comment: You can't replace the elements through `operator[]` under the other alternative, either.